# ASP MVC Url Encode double escape sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encode

I want to encrypt the Id part of a given url and I used [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithms) for that. This algorithm convert the id to the following string:

> NxVhIhrfbZNzyxqtudUZdiv4DdQA9nF1Zn7CueGUiT8=|h1bCRiN5zxexiIhHp+qNEQ0jVh/8fMGiIkeTf30LVdU=

Therefore, my final url would be something like this:

```
http://localhost:9432/Product/Edit/NxVhIhrfbZNzyxqtudUZdiv4DdQA9nF1Zn7CueGUiT8=|h1bCRiN5zxexiIhHp+qNEQ0jVh/8fMGiIkeTf30LVdU=
```

This url has some character which cause the request fail. For example ‘+’ is not allowed in url. So I used `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` on the encrypted Id and got this string as a result:

> NxVhIhrfbZNzyxqtudUZdiv4DdQA9nF1Zn7CueGUiT8%3d%7ch1bCRiN5zxexiIhHp%2bqNEQ0jVh%2f8fMGiIkeTf30LVdU%3d

Now my url is:

```
http://localhost:9432/Product/Edit/NxVhIhrfbZNzyxqtudUZdiv4DdQA9nF1Zn7CueGUiT8%3d%7ch1bCRiN5zxexiIhHp%2bqNEQ0jVh%2f8fMGiIkeTf30LVdU%3d
```

However using the above url cause the following error:

> The request contained a double escape sequence and request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny double escape sequences.

I can ignore that by inserting the below code in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Now I have two questions:

1. Why the result of `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` causes any kind of error. As I noticed, the result of that doesn’t contain any illegal character for a url?
2. As I understood putting `<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />` is not a good solution, since it will create a security hole in the application, so what would be the best solution in this case?

Comment: This helped me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36382162/3389046.

Answer (score 4):

the result of HttpUtility.UrlEncode() doesn't contain errors, it is just encoding the + sign with will be detected on IIS level. IIS rejects "+" in URLs by default. Your work around will work:

```
<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
```

but as you said, it will create some security problems because this makes your site more vulnerable to malicious URLs.

What i suggest, either you use another encryption algorithm that doesn't generate these "IIS" sensetive characters, or if you wanna use the above workaround, you need to implement proper URL/User-Input validations in order to make sure that you catch and prevent all suspecious entries.